# How to measure how much memory usage of an expression or the whole program in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I would like to measure how much memory an expression is using for my program or even an expression?

Is there an easy way to do this in Racket? 
Documentation involves using some custodian, which I am not sure how it works.....

Demo code snippet appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "accounting of memory usage"?  Do you want to know how much memory an expression is using?  Or do you want to limit how much memory an expression can use?  Or something else?

Comment: @SamTobin-Hochstadt "how much memory an expression is using".

Comment: Need clarification.  You probably mean that you want to measure the amount of memory used in **evaluating** an expression.  The distinction is important: otherwise you're asking how much memory the actual expression data structure is using, which is a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since i don't use racket as my lisp i can't be sure if there are builtins, but in the 
meantime you can use this:
https://github.com/samth/gcstats

cheers.

Comment: I tried it on Racket, got this error `default-load-handler: cannot open directory as a file: ".../gcstats" (errno=?)` `...` represents the path where I installed gcstats. Am I missing something?

Comment: please give me some time, you are right , i can reproduce it on x64 linux. From a quick strace i saw there is something going on with double paths (like ./gcstats/gcstats/.../) . I got in contact with the developer so i will have feedback soon. sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: Hello again! Ok it was a mistake on our part but the developer updated the README file on github. You have to run it as follows:
`% racket -l gcstats normal-racket-arguments`

For example:

`% racket -l gcstats -t "foo.rkt"`

or

`% racket -l gcstats -l drracket`